# Why is Atlanta Georgia becoming the new Hollywood?

Tags: film-industry, film-location, american-cinema

I have been noticing more and more that a lot of movies have been filmed in Atlanta Georgia and that many still continue to be filmed there.

Is the city just becoming even more popular than usual or is there some incentive to the geographic location, places to shoot, climate, scenery, or entertainment industry professionals? Or was it a legal incentive of some sort?

Comment: The hot new place to film changes every five years or so, and many times more than one place is trending. I know Vancouver was and maybe still is a popular shooting city, at least for TV. There are many reasons for such things but I’ll keave it to someone who can write a full answer about it. Unless there’s a specific need for a certain project, I very much doubt the number of strip clubs is a factor at all.

Answer (score 7):

Simply....

## Money

There are significant tax incentives for film production in Georgia (both movie & TV)

*Time* has an excellent article online

> Georgia has been working to attract Hollywood since 2008, when then governor Sonny Perdue signed a generous tax incentive for film productions. Thomas says officials lobbied for the measure after the state lost the production of Ray, the biopic about Georgia native Ray Charles that won Jamie Foxx an Oscar, to Louisiana. **Georgia now offers a 20% incentive on productions of $500,000 or more, plus an additional 10% if the film adds a peach logo to its credits.** The incentives are similar to those in states like New York and Louisiana, but in Georgia, unlike those states, the law has no end date.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://time.com/longform/hollywood-in-georgia/)</sup>
>
> In 2007, the film industry spent $93 million on productions in Georgia. In 2016, it spent over $2 billion. **In the past decade, the tax perk has attracted the Hunger Games franchise, the Fast and Furious movies and superproducer Tyler Perry, who has made the state his base. Television hits like Stranger Things, critical darlings like Atlanta and reality series like The Real Housewives of Atlanta have all set up shop in the capital, often for years at a time.** Georgia’s government estimates that in 2016 alone, the film industry gave the state a $7 billion economic boost through job creation and tourism.

...and co-operation

> **It takes more than tax incentives to lure productions**. “It’s not enough to just get us here,” says Walking Dead producer Tom Luse, a Georgia native who began his career as a production manager on the Georgia-based film Glory. “The mayor [of Senoia] and state are eager to help, allowing us to shut down bridges and streets and take over towns.”

Comment: Georgia also has a lot of landscape diversity in close proximity. You can go from mountains to the sea in three hours. That saves a lot of money for some productions. Disney is shooting a film in Savannah right now where that is a huge factor. Same is true of California, but they have made it terribly expensive to shoot there.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your insight and input. I figured it was because of money one way or another. Didn't really think about how diverse the landscape is but I guess you are right. Not too far from water, mountains and a large city with beautiful scenery and attractions. I appreciate it guys! :)